# How does the Sympa integration deal with unsubscribes

Tags: email

We're looking at the various listserv options, e.g. mailman, sympa, mailchimp that have some sort of integration to civi.

So if someone receives an email via Sympa integrated to civi and wants to unsubscribe, how is it handled?  What is the process?

Answer (score 2):

[CiviCRM-Sympa Syncronization](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.sympasync) includes unsubscription pages (it was introduced with [this commit](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.sympasync/commit/85393d13ccad9c3dc5d2bfcd22d1e6869ad17a99)). On « sympasync » configuration page (`https://example.org/civicrm/a/#/sympa/admin`), you’ll find the URL that can be added to your list’s footer. URL will look like `https://example.org/civicrm/sympa/unsubscribe?gid=1`.

Problem is that you can’t override the default unsubscription mechanism in Sympa, so you’ll need to disable the ability for users to unsubscribe in your list configuration (to force them to use sympasync’s link). If you let Sympa’s default mechanism, people will be able to unsubscribe (and it will be effective), but information won’t be pushed back to CiviCRM.

So by adding the unsubscription link at the end of each mail sent on your Sympa mailing list and by disabling the ability to unsubscribe in your list configuration, you’ll get what you want.

Comment: Hmm, just to be clear, you're saying that by using sympasync, disabling user unsubscription in sympa and including the link, civi will be updated with unsubscribes.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. CiviCRM’s unsubscription page will remove people from the group.

Answer (score 1):

Which sympa extension do you want to use? The way the unsubscribe is handled is pretty much how the extension you looked at implemented it (and if you plan to use one I wrote a long time ago, it isn't handled ;(

Comment: The only one I came across is org.civicrm.sympasync.  https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.sympasync.  Are there others?  There seems to be a number of changes done Oct 15 that appear to add unsubscribe pages.